# Trafic data more than 500GB with Ruby cache 16 Cpus , is it normal size

Tags: gem5

the traffic file is around 500GB for running Ruby  !! , it is normal or not, please? 
what is my problem, and which size of traffic should be?

sudo scons FULL_SYSTEM=1 build/ALPHA/gem5.opt RUBY=true  PROTOCOL=MOESI_hammer

./build/ALPHA/gem5.opt -d m5out/blackscholes --debug-flags=RubyCache  --debug-file=trace.out.gz  configs/example/fs.py --ruby  --num-cpu=16 --l1i_size=32kB --l1d_size=32kB --l2_size=8MB --cpu-type=timing --restore-with-cpu=timing --script=run_scripts/blackscholes_16c_simsmall.rcS --checkpoint-at-end --kernel=/home/xx/gem5/full_system_images_ALPHA/binaries/vmlinux_2.6.27-gcc_4.3.4 --disk-image=/home/xxx/gem5/full_system_images_ALPHA/disks/linux-parsec-2-1-m5-with-test-inputs.img --max-checkpoints=5

i used  debug-flags=RubyCache,

Comment: I would just compare that to the instruction count and see if the ratio seems reasonable. If not, try to inspect the traces to understand, and if not possible, look into baremetal SE.py minimal examples that you fully understand to debug. Multi Giga logs are not unheard of in gem5 world.